# Shadertoy - SDF with Texture Mapping

Tags: 3d, glsl

Dabbling from 2D SDF's to 3D SDF's in Shaderoy.
*SDF = Signed Distance Field
I've scoured the web for information regarding texturing a 3D SDF object, to find nothing.

Main Goal:
To map an Image from iChannel0 to a hexagonal prism.
This prism will be rotating around.
(Picture a pencil rotating and reading words written on the edges which would be mapped from iChannel0).
[image]
(Simple SDF HexPrism with a plane to show shadow).

I have read in ways to store pixel information in the actual intersection point, like the material ID, and Tri-Planar Mapping and such, but when this rotates, all of that goes out the window.
I thought of just getting rid of the plane and rotating the camera around the prism, which could work but then I still have the issue of ensuring that the image stored gets mapped correctly to all sides of the hex.

Any direction, website or book on this would be much appreciated.
If it just can't be done, then can someone suggest a different method instead of Ray-Marching and SDF's for Shadertoy that will work?

[EDIT]
[image]

Mainly the issue that I'm having is ID'ing the sides of the prism.
As it rotates the ray hits the closest point on the prism, there really isn't a way to ID that side to coordinate it correctly with the map.

I could essentially build this out of 6 quads with each quad having it's own ID, which would work, but of course be a royal pain.

Thanks!

Comment: Just rotate the uv's as well as the SDF?

Comment: I'm looking in to setting up a local UV of sorts, like a bounding box.  Instead of using a Tri-Planar approach, I'm going to see if I can map the uv's to a 6-Plane using the bounding box. When the object rotates, the bounding box/6-Plane will rotate with it. Hmm..

Comment: U have to manually unwrap it pretty much like in 3d modeling soft. when creating a uv.
https://www.shadertoy.com/view/3ld3DB

Comment: Interesting approach, the code is not well documented at all, which isn't going to help anyone unless they know this stuff inside and out. Plus your chars are mirrored on 1 side which is incorrect as it rotates.